# Mockito spy not mocking internal call to mocked method

Tags: java, mockito

I have a class that calls out to a third party system to get data that I want to mock using Mockito. Here is some pseudo-code of how my class is setup.

```
// class I will be spying
public class SomeService {
    // method I want to full test
    public List<String> methodA(List<String> list) {
        ... omitted code ...
        // internal call to method in the same class that will be mocked
        innerList = methodB(list);
        ... omitted code ...
    }

    // method that I want to mock/spy
    public List<String> methodB(List<String> list) {
        //details omitted since it should be mocked any never called
    }
}
```

Here is my test code. I setup my spy in a BeforeEach method to make sure that Mock is configured. When I directly call the mocked method, everything works as expected. When I call

```
public class SomeServiceTest{

    private SomeService service;

    @BeforeEach
    public void init() {
        service = Mockito.spy(SomeService.class);
        // also tried with creating a new object but has same failure conditions
        //service = Mockito.spy(new SomeService());

        // mocking methodB with answer details omitted to reduce clutter
        Mockito.doAnswer(..detail omitted..).when(service).methodB(Mockito.anyList());
    }

    //testing directly calling mocked method that returns mocked data
    @Test
    public void testMockedMethod() throws Exception {
        List<String> list = //setup details ignored
        List<String> results = service.methodB(list);
        // follow up asserts work
    }

    //testing indirectly calling mocked method that call actual method code
    @Test
    public void testMethodA() throws Exception {
        List<String> list = //setup details ignored
        // NullPointer in methodB since mocking is ignore
        List<String> results = service.methodA(list);
        // assertions never tested since NPE was thrown
    }
}
```

Does anyone know why when I directly call the mocked method, it returns the doAnswer; but when I indirectly call from within the mocked/spied object it ignores the fact that the method is mocked and calls the original method?

Answer (score 0):

It should work. It seems to me that the NPE exception is because there are some bugs in your codes which already happen before it really executes the stubbed method . What is the stacktrack that you get ?

On the other hand, you can also add some `println` just before and after calling the stubbed method to verify the codes is really can execute up to that point :

```java
 public List<String> methodA(List<String> list) {
    .......
    System.out.println("before methodB");
    innerList = methodB(list);
    System.out.println("after methodB which return " + innerList);
    ....
}
```

Comment: The stacktrace for the NPE is inside the call of methodB since I didn't initialize the client that calls out to the 3rd party system. I just find it odd that directly calling the mocked method works, but having it called from within the spy will call the actual method instead of using the mocked method. I also updated mockito-core to 4.5.1 so I know that it isn't an older version issue.

Comment: what is that client to call 3rd party system ?  show me more about the codes of `SomeService` , esp. the codes related to this client. It should work